# Search Function Using Queries and Controls

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to utilize a search function on a form. I based the form on a query that is a copy of the table, except the criteria are linked to a control on the form. Ex.

```
WHERE (((tblFamily.FamilyName) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmFamily]![cntrlFamilyName] & "*")
```

I want to do this in other fields such as address, city, etc. as well. However, if I apply the same logic to the address field, blank records are ignored and never returned, even if nothing was put into the control.

How do I fix it so that when nothing is put in to the cntrlAddress the search does not ignore records with blank addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append an empty string to your field and search on that:

```
WHERE tblFamily.FamilyName & "" 
   Like "*" & [Forms]![frmFamily]![cntrlFamilyName] & "*"
```

This will mean that `tblFamily.FamilyName` will not be null and when `[Forms]![frmFamily]![cntrlFamilyName]` is empty, the query will read:

```
Where "" Like "*"
Where "bob" Like "*"
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks again! Learning a little at a time.